# How to insert some values in all the html inputs of specific div, on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple forms in a single page.
Every form is is in different `<div>`, I want to insert some values in html inputs, present in a specific `<div>`, Please tell what I am doing wrong?

```
function onLoadPopulateInputs(){
    var digits = getDateTimeOnLoad();
    console.log("DT "+digits)
    $('.input').value = digits #I think here is someting wrong!!!
    }

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoadPopulateInputs);
```

My Input looks like this:

```
<input size="16" type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function onLoadPopulateInputs(){
    var digits = getDateTimeOnLoad();
    console.log("DT "+digits);
    var $yourDiv = $('#yourDiv');
    $yourDiv.find('input').val(digits);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoadPopulateInputs);
```

Comment: here you select every input regardless of the parent `div`

Comment: @NimChimpsky it was edited meanwhile... before it was just `$('input')`

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#yourDiv > input').val(digits)
```

your selector is borked

Comment: @ Nim Chimpsky: I have just tried the same but no positive response.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a class for div containing 'forms' :

```
<div class="formDiv">
    <input />
    ....
</div>


<div class="formDiv">
    <input />
    ....
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.formDiv').each(function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('input').each(function(){
        $(this).val(someValue);
    });
});
```

Usage exemple http://jsfiddle.net/techunter/EzWpu/

**Why this instead of just `$('input')` or `$('#myDiv input')` like proposed by other?**

Well because here you can manage context and control everything. also you said you have multiple forms inside multiple div : "multiple" == make it generic and use **class** not **id**. If you need to edit a specific value maybe consider faster selection using ID or `$('#myDiv input[name="myInputName"])` or equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.val`

```
$('.input').val(digits);
```

Comment: that will select all elements with class input, which is nto correct I a imagine

Comment: @NimChimpsky The issue here is different i.e _setting the value_

Comment: I disagree I think there are 2 issues, no mention of a class called input. except in the snippet. If there is, OP shold change it.

Answer (score 0):

give your specific div an id and call an id selector..

```
function onLoadPopulateInputs(){
  var digits = getDateTimeOnLoad();
  console.log("DT "+digits)
   $('#divID input').val(digits);
}
```

jquery method of setting  a value of input is `.val()` and not `.value`

Comment: `.input` is a class not a tag

Comment: @TecHunter input is defintely a tag, whether it is class here is up for debate I think

Comment: @NimChimpsky what I meant is selecting .input will not select the input tags